# Time Complexity of a While loop that increments from 2 to x where x^2 <= N

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Is the time complexity of a While loop that increments from 2 to x where x^2 <= N  `O(lg n)` ? 
Can somebody give some explanation?

Here's the example of the code:

```
public static boolean isSquare(long num) {
    if ((num <= 1) && (num > 0)) 
        return true;

    long currentNumber = 2;
    long currentSquare = 4;

    while (currentSquare <= num) {
        if (currentSquare == num)
            return true;

        currentNumber++;
        currentSquare = currentNumber * currentNumber;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Which one do you suppose is asymptotically higher - sqrt(N) or log(N)?

Comment: No, it's not logarithmic. It's worse than logarithmic: it's `O(sqrt(N))`, which is polynomial.

Comment: sqrt(N) is higher. Thanks, I get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this complexity is *O(sqrt(n))*.  You are varying the number by squares, and comparing it to the square of a number.  Or you could increment it by 1 and compare with the square root of the number.